# Why is request.data empty?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on DRF
When I visit post_list through local server, It gives me correct data.
but When I do test, It gives me empty list.
How can I fix it?

tests.py

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse as api_reverse
from rest_framework import status

from .models import Post


class PostAPITestCase(APITestCase):
    def test_posts(self):
        url = api_reverse('item:list')
        response = self.client.get(url, format='json')
        print(response.data) # [] ???
```

views.py

```
class PostListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.all()
```

Comment: Show your view function.

Comment: Looks like you need to create records for testing.

Comment: Sooooooooooooooooooooooooooo Thank you @funnydman